# Entire PHP script being echo'd out instead of specific line

Tags: php

**MCVE:**

```
<?php

    echo "testing!";

?>
```

**Screenshot from accessing this script in Chrome:**

[image: chrome screenshot]

**Screenshot from running this script via the PHP command-line:**

[image: cmd screenshot]

What's weird is that it hasn't always been this way. Everything was working perfectly yesterday, but ever since today, it's been doing this for whatever reason. Did I screw something up within the config of my Apache accidentally or something? Using XAMPP with PHP v7.3.8.

Comment: The spacing in the output of the command-line looks a bit suspicious. You could check the character encoding of the PHP file in your editor. Also, in the output the first `<` seems to be missing. Missing information: Does this occur with all PHP files? Old ones and new ones?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yep the character encoding is what it was, good catch, thank you! No idea how it got changed.

Comment: It happens... My FTP client once did something similar...

Answer (score 0):

Wow, good catch [KIKO Software](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3986005/kiko-software)! After checking the encoding of the file in Notepad++... I realized that it, for some reason, was set to "UCS-2 LE BOM". I changed it to "UTF-8" and now everything is working properly. Thank you!

Comment: Ah, nice. No idea what "UCS-2 LE BOM" is, but it is clearly not good. 